# How can I get the customer remote address(ip) in javascript? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I couldn't find any javascript file that would get the remote address(ip). I am thinking of creating my own javascript helper with api, but maybe there is a better way or the javascript that I am looking for already exists.

Any help is welcome, tnx fellas :)

Answer (score 1):

You get the ip of the customer with javascript using WebRTC, not all browsers support this check [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=WebRTC).

```
function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  }
  pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    });
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop); // create offer and set local description
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}



var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.textContent = 'Your IPs are: '
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function addIP(ip) {
  console.log('got ip: ', ip);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = ip;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841164/1016425

Or you can try this instead:

```
$.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Or check this post for multiple ways of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/1016425

Answer (score 0):

You can assign $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to to JavaScript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RemoteAddress  = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>';
    console.log(RemoteAddress);
</script>
```

> you can use this RemoteAddress variable in js file as well but make
>   sure you call this before including js files

Comment: This would raise the issue of where to put the code, a good solution however.

Comment: Yes. You need to put in global template like page/html/head.phtml in magento 1.x. not sure for magento2